# Does build automation really help productivity even without unit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins, junit, build-automation

In our current project, we don't actually practice unit testing. Our bosses are encouraging us to go for build automation like Jenkins. Will a build automation tool really help us in productivity or quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will *probably* help a bit, but not as much as with tests to back it up.

For example, build automation, if configured for every attempt to submit code, will ensure that if the build fails, i.e. can't compile, then either the code is prevented from entering the main branch where everyone else is working or at the very least, make sure everyone is aware the build is broken. This depends on whether your build automation runs before or after the code is merged to the branch everyone else is working on.

This would ensure that at a minimum the code at least compiles, and therefore that others on the team don't have to wrestle with code that doesn't compile and lose time trying to pinpoint errors in other code.

Depending on how much build automation is included, you might even have deliverable artifacts ready to be manually tested which saves the time of performing those builds.

But that's about the limit of it, unless you have some tests.

As a side note, the reason I said *probably*, is none of it is worth anything unless attention is paid to the results. If the results are there but never really followed up on, then the reality is zero value.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, automating your build will improve your productivity and quality even if you haven't written any tests yet. You won't have to build manually every time someone wants a build to test or release, and you'll find out faster if you have a compilation or other build error.

But you should certainly write tests as well, and run them automatically too.